# Get the CPU usage of a particular process by processID

Tags: java, windows, powershell, process, wmic

I am trying to get the exact cpu usage of a particular process using the PID.

Using Wmic , i am able to get the cpu memory , threadcount but not the CPU usage.

using typeperf , we can get the cpu time[i am not sure what the time is excatly]

`typeperf -sc 5 "\process(w3wp)\% processor time"`

output

`"09/16/2014 10:43:34.441","1.556741"
"09/16/2014 10:43:35.443","3.113481"
"09/16/2014 10:43:36.446","0.000000"
"09/16/2014 10:43:37.449","0.000000"
"09/16/2014 10:43:38.452","0.000000"`

is there any way to find the exact CPU [%] usage of the running windows/java process ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a relatively straightforward way of doing this in Powershell with either the PID or name (Use either Option A or Option B)

```
# Option A: This is if you just have the name
$ProcessName = "ProcessName"

# Option B: This is for if you just have the PID; it will get the name for you
$ProcessPID = "3348"
$ProcessName = (Get-Process -Id $ProcessPID).Name


$CpuCores = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Processor).NumberOfCores
$CpuValue = ((Get-Counter "\Process($ProcessName)\% Processor Time").CounterSamples.CookedValue)/$CpuCores
[Decimal]::Round($CpuValue, 3)
```

I hope this helps solve your issue or at least point you in the right direction.

Cheers,

**EDIT**:  I didn't realize the issues that would popup when using older versions of powershell and different machines that were VM's or had multiple physical cpu's, so... here's my edit to the script.

```
# Option A: This is if you just have the name
$ProcessName = "ProcessName"

# Option B: This is for if you just have the PID; it will get the name for you
$ProcessPID = "3348"
$ProcessName = (Get-Process -Id $ProcessPID).Name

$CpuCores = (Get-WMIObject Win32_ComputerSystem).NumberOfLogicalProcessors
$CpuValue = ((Get-Counter "\Process($ProcessName)\% Processor Time").CounterSamples | Select-Object -Property CookedValue).CookedValue
[Decimal]::Round($CpuValue, 3)
```

Comment: i am getting an error on executing this


`Missing or invalid array index expression.
At line:1 char:108
+ $CpuValue = ((Get-Counter "\Process($ProcessName)\% Processor Time").CounterSamples.CookedValue)/$CpuCores[ <<<< Deci
mal]::Round($CpuValue, 3)
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: ([:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArrayIndexExpression`

can you pls help me here

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  I see that you posted a reply to yourself already, but I figured I'd update my answer as well.  I ran into similar issues on VM's and machines with more than one physical cpu.  I'll edit my original answer in the hopes that that may someday help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I found an solution to get all the process related details with respect to ProcessID using PowerShell

Below is the powershell code to get the required process details , including cpu usage of a particular Process.

```
 param(
[String]$ProcID = "0" ,
[String[]]$Get = "0"
)
$CPUPercent = @{
  Name = 'CPUPercent'
  Expression = {
    $TotalSec = (New-TimeSpan -Start $_.StartTime).TotalSeconds
    [Math]::Round( ($_.CPU * 100 / $TotalSec), 2)
  }
}
function getParameters($Query)
{
    switch($Query)
    {
        "Name" {
                (Get-Process -ID $ProcID).Name | Format-List
               }
        "Pid" {
                (Get-Process -ID $ProcID).ProcessId | Format-List
               }
        "CommandLine" {
                        (Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -filter "ProcessId=$ProcID").CommandLine | Format-List
                      }
        "CSName" {
                        (Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -filter "ProcessId=$ProcID").CSName | 
                        Format-List
                      }
        "Description" {
                        (Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -filter "ProcessId=$ProcID").Description |                         
                        Format-List
                      }
        "ExecutablePath" {
                        (Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -filter "ProcessId=$ProcID").ExecutablePath |                      
                        Format-List
                      }
        "MaximumWorkingSetSize" {
                        (Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -filter "ProcessId=$ProcID").MaximumWorkingSetSize |                       
                        Format-List
                      }
        "MinimumWorkingSetSize" {
                        (Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -filter "ProcessId=$ProcID").MinimumWorkingSetSize |                       
                        Format-List
                      } 
        "PageFaults" {
                        (Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -filter "ProcessId=$ProcID").PageFaults |                      
                        Format-List
                      }
        "PeakVirtualSize" {
                        (Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -filter "ProcessId=$ProcID").PeakVirtualSize |                         
                        Format-List
                      }             
        "ProcessName" {
                        (Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -filter "ProcessId=$ProcID").ProcessName |                         
                        Format-List
                      }
        "ThreadCount" {
                        (Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -filter "ProcessId=$ProcID").ThreadCount | 
                        Format-list
                      } 
        "CPU"       {
                        (Get-Process -ID $ProcID) |
                        Select-Object -Property $CPUPercent|
                        Format-list
                    }       
        "PSVersion" {
                        $PSversiontable.psversion.major |
                        Format-list
                      }                       
        default {
                        "Not Enough Parameters for Get"
                        "Usage : example : ProcessDetails.ps1 -ProcID 5988 -Get cpu"
                }
    }
}
if(!($ProcID -eq "0") -or !($Get -eq "0"))
{
    foreach($getParam in $Get)
    {
        getParameters($getParam)
    }
}
else
{
    "Not Enough Parameters"
    "Usage : example : XXX.ps1 -ProcID PPPP -Get cpu"
}
```

Usage : just copy this code to a file and execute using power shell

ex : .\XXX.ps1 -ProcID 1000 -Get cpu

ex : .\XXX.ps1 -ProcID 1000 -Get ExecutablePath

ex : .\XXX.ps1 -ProcID 1000 -Get ExecutablePath,cpu